# Unable to bind ngModel

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I just started learning Angular and everything is pretty new to me. I have started a course and I got stuck with one part. When I try to do two way property binding, the ngModel is not working as expected.

This is the user.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../models/User';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css'],
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
    user: User = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    age: 0,
    address: {
      street: '',
      city: '',
      state: ''
    }
  }
  users: User[];
  showExtended: boolean = true;
  loaded: boolean = false;
  enableAdd: boolean = true;
  showUserForm: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    this.users = this.getUserDefaults();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.loaded = true;
  }

  

  private getUserDefaults() {
    return [
      {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        age: 65,
        address: {
          street: '50 Main st',
          city: 'Boston',
          state: 'MA',
        },
        isActive: true,
        registered: new Date('01/02/2018 08:30:00'),
        hide: true
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Kevin',
        lastName: 'Johnson',
        age: 34,
        address: {
          street: '20 School st',
          city: 'Lynn',
          state: 'MA',
        },
        isActive: false,
        registered: new Date('03/11/2017 06:20:00'),
        hide: true
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Karen',
        lastName: 'Williams',
        age: 26,
        address: {
          street: '55 Mill st',
          city: 'Miami',
          state: 'FL',
        },
        isActive: true,
        registered: new Date('11/02/2016 10:30:00'),
        hide: true
      },
    ];


  }

  addUser(user: User) {
    this.users.push(user);
  }

  // toggleHide(user: User) {
  //   user.hide = !user.hide;
  // }

  onSubmit(e: any) {
    console.log(123)
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  fireEvent(e: any) {
    console.log(e.type)
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }
 
}
```

This is the users.component.html file

```
<button (click)="showUserForm = !showUserForm" class="btn btn-dark mb-3">Add User</button>
<div class="card card-body mb-3" *ngIf="showUserForm">
  <h2>Add User</h2>
  <form (submit)="onSubmit($event)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="user.firstName">
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" [(ngModel)]="user.lastName">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Age</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="age" [(ngModel)]="user.age">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Street Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="street" [(ngModel)]="user.address.street">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>City</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" [(ngModel)]="user.address.city">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>State</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state" [(ngModel)]="user.address.state">
      </div>
    <button (click)="addUser({ firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jackson', isActive:true})" [disabled]="!enableAdd" class="btn btn-block mb-3">
      Add New User
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
<h2>Users</h2>

<ul class="list-unstyled" *ngIf="loaded && users.length > 0">
  <li class="card card-body mb-2" *ngFor="let user of users" [class.bg-light]="user.isActive">
    <h3>{{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }} <small *ngIf="user.age && user.address"><button (click)="user.hide = !user.hide" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"><i [ngClass]="user.hide ? 'fa fa-plus' : 'fa fa-minus'" class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></small></h3>
    <ul class="list-group" *ngIf="!user.hide && user.age && user.address">
      <li class="list-group-item">Age: {{ user.age }}</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Address: {{ user.address.street }}, {{ user.address.city }},
        {{ user.address.state }}
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Joined: {{ user.registered | date }}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<h4 *ngIf="users.length == 0">No Users Found</h4>

<h4 *ngIf="!loaded">Loading Users...</h4>
```

And this is the interface

```
export interface User {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    age?: number,
    address?: {
        street?: string,
        city?: string,
        state?: string
    },
    isActive?: boolean,
    registered?: any,
    hide?: boolean
}
```

In the html file where I have the inputs the ngModel is not working as expected. I am trying to bind these inputs with

```
    user: User = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    age: 0,
    address: {
      street: '',
      city: '',
      state: ''
    }
  }
```

ngModel for firstName, lastName and age works just fine. But when I try to bind ngModel with user.address.street or user.address.city or user.address.state, I get the follwoing error:

```
Error: src/app/components/users/users.component.html:19:89 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

19         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="street" [(ngModel)]="user.address.street">
                                                                                           ~~~~~~

  src/app/components/users/users.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './users.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component UsersComponent.
```

Does anybody know why is this happening and how to fix this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try safe navigation operator: `[(ngModel)]="user.address?.street"`, `[(ngModel)]="user.address?.city"` and `[(ngModel)]="user.address?.state"`.

Comment: Safe navigation operator works in the users.components.ts file, but not in the html file. Tried it before.
This error pops up:
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at 
column 22 in [user.address?.street=$event] in C:\Users\kobol\JS codes\Angular\Projects\angularapp\src\app\components\users\users.component.html@18:75

Comment: The aforementioned statement `[user.address.street=$event]` isn't available in the original question.

Comment: This error popped up after I added the ? to the user.address?.street

Comment: Problem solved. All I had to do is to add this before user.address.street. So now it looks like this. this.user.address.street, this.user.address.city, this.user.address.state. I don't know why it is working this way, but it works.